# Replace mongodb document without appending attributes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I think I have a weird one here.

I'm using mongoose in express to update a document in a collection. The model looks like this:

```
var customers = new Schema({
companyName: String,
addressLine1: String,
addressLine2: String,
city: String,
province: String,
postal: String,
businessPhone: String,
contacts: [{
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    title: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
}],
custCode: Number,
rep: String
});
```

Above is a new model, as the old model looked like this:

```
var customers = new Schema({
companyName: String,
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
addressLine1: String,
addressLine2: String,
city: String,
province: String,
postal: String,
businessPhone: String,      
email: String
custCode: Number,
rep: String
});
```

The difference is that I broke out a "contacts" array so I can add more contacts in the future. Existing documents in the collection have the old style of model and the update object has the new model.

When I run the following code, the document ends up getting appended with the contacts array, but also keeps the firstName and lastName, email etc instead of losing it as per the rules of the new model.

```
var conditions = {custCode:req.body.customer.custCode}
, update = req.body.customer
, options = {upsert: false, new: true};

mongoose.model('customers').findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback);
function callback (err, doc) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Errors: " + err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      console.log("Customer Saved! Rows affected: ", doc);
      res.sendStatus(200); 
    };
  };
```

Is there a different mongoose function that I should be using? Should I be using $unset?

I'd rather not do two calls to the database (one to remove the matching collection and another to save a new model.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$unset` to remove the `contacts` array and `$set` to add the new model.

`mongoose.model('customers').findOneAndUpdate(conditions, { $set:update, $unset: {'contacts': ''}}, options, callback);`

Answer (score 1):

`findOneAndUpdate` modifies an existing document with the new data.

The options you have provided don't modify document replacement.

- `upsert` affects creation of new documents when the current doesn't exist.
- `new` affects which data is returned by the function. pre or post update.

If you have the complete set of data in the `update` variable, you can completely replace the existing document with [`replaceOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.replaceOne)

```
mongoose.model('customers').replaceOne(conditions, update, options, callback);
function callback (err, doc) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Errors: " + err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
      console.log("Customer Saved! Rows affected: ", doc);
      res.sendStatus(200); 
    };
  };
```